# Difference between two ways of defining class template constructors

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement my custom version of shared_ptr and weak_ptr. While implementing them, I've got into some problems with it.

In order to accept subclass types from constructor, I had to use another template type U as parameter other than template type of the class 'T'.

Let's say constructor with parameter type U as version 1
and constructor with parameter type T as version 2

Here's my question

- Why does version 2 gets called when I initialize class template with same type?

```cpp
WeakPtr<T> weakPtr_a;
WeakPtr<T> weakPtr_b = weakPtr_a; //Shouldn't this be still enough with version 1?
```

- In which cases does version 2 gets called? Is this implementation feasible?

Here are my code snippets

**WeakPtr-Decl.hpp**

```cpp
template <typename T>
class WeakPtr
{
    T* m_objectPtr = nullptr;

    SharedObjectInfo* m_sharedObjectInfoPtr = nullptr;

    template <typename U>
    friend class WeakPtr;

 public:
    constexpr WeakPtr();

    ~WeakPtr() = default;

    //! Copy constructor
    //! \tparam U : template type of weakPtr to copy from
    //! U must be same type as T or subclass of T or assertion will fail
    //! \param weakPtr : weakPtr to copy from
    template <typename U>
    WeakPtr(const WeakPtr<U>& weakPtr); // Version 1

    //! Copy constructor
    //! \param weakPtr : weakPtr to copy from
    WeakPtr(const WeakPtr<T>& weakPtr); // Version 2
};
```

**WeakPtr-Impl.hpp**

```cpp
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
WeakPtr<T>::WeakPtr(const WeakPtr<U>& weakPtr)
    : m_objectPtr(weakPtr.m_objectPtr),
      m_sharedObjectInfoPtr(weakPtr.m_sharedObjectInfoPtr)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>>::value ||
                  std::is_base_of<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>>::value);
}

template <typename T>
WeakPtr<T>::WeakPtr(const WeakPtr<T>& weakPtr)
    : m_objectPtr(weakPtr.m_objectPtr),
      m_sharedObjectInfoPtr(weakPtr.m_sharedObjectInfoPtr)
{
}
```

Comment: When multiple functions are eligible to be used, the compiler looks for the [best viable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function). Rule 4 says that a non-templated version is preferred over a template specialization.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Do you see better way of implementing this? I don't want to declare two versions constructors or methods with template parameter types.

Comment: You can implement the non-templated version by delegating to the templated version: `A(const A& b) : A<A>(b) {}`.

Comment: You should keep both constructor as the regular copy constructor does not need any extra validation. If you have common code to execute after initialization, then you can call a common constructor or initialization function. Alternatively, template constructor can forward to default constructor after a `static_cast` (and appropriate checks)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comments, when available an exact non-template constructor (version 2, in your case), it's preferred over a template one (version 1).

I suggest to use delegating constructor, so let the compiler choose the version 2 (when the type is the same) and, from version 2, call version 1.

I propose to add an unused defaulted second parameter in version 1

```
  template <typename U> // ............VVVVVVV
  WeakPtr (WeakPtr<U> const & weakPtr, int = 0)
     : m_objectPtr{weakPtr.m_objectPtr},
       m_sharedObjectInfoPtr{weakPtr.m_sharedObjectInfoPtr}
   {  }
```

and transform version 2 as follows

```
  WeakPtr (WeakPtr const & weakPtr) : WeakPtr{weakPtr, 0}
   { }
```

The second unused parameter in version 1 is added to permit to select version 1 calling it from version 2.

Observe the zero in `WeakPtr{weakPtr, 0}` in delegating call in version 2: the added zero force the call of version 1 because version 2 has only one argument.

The default value is important to permit the direct use of version 1 when the types are different.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me better way! II'll try this